# Why new Date().getTime() returns too much "0" in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp

I'm trying to get a timestamp from a date in javascript but `new Date(2013, 03, 17).getTime()` return `1366149600000` which is wrong (1981-2-2 23:11:12). If I remove the three last zeros, I get the good date.

Where the problem come from ?

Comment: Do you realize it is milliseconds, not seconds? The Docs: [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

it returns milliseconds, unix timestamp are in seconds hence your need to remove the last 3 digits

Comment: If I remove a day (86400000ms) to this timestamp : 1364767200000 (1st of April), I get 30-3-2013 23:00:00 but I want 31-03-2013 ; is it normal ?

Answer (score 4):

As per Damien's answer, you will get milliseconds so basically you have to divide the .getTime() result per 1000

getTime() / 1000 => good unixtimestamp